# Quickblox open image as WhatsApp

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, quickblox

How to open image as WhatsApp do after image preview click

The code for QuickBlox Sample Demo [code link](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios)

New quickblox api image attachment working fine but when I click image it is not opening.
I have tried with this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

> I am using this method in `UICollectionView` cell for image click but it is not working.

complete method code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(QMChatCollectionView *)collectionView configureCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    [super collectionView:collectionView configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [(QMChatCell *)cell containerView].highlightColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[QMChatOutgoingCell class]] || [cell isKindOfClass:[QMChatAttachmentOutgoingCell class]]) {
    [(QMChatIncomingCell *)cell containerView].bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:121.0f/255.0f blue:1 alpha:1.0f];
    } else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[QMChatIncomingCell class]] || [cell isKindOfClass:[QMChatAttachmentIncomingCell class]]) {
    [(QMChatOutgoingCell *)cell containerView].bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0f / 255.0f green:231.0f / 255.0f blue:231.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }

   if ([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(QMChatAttachmentCell)]) {
    QBChatMessage* message = [self messageForIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (message.attachments != nil) {
        QBChatAttachment* attachment = message.attachments.firstObject;

        NSMutableArray* keysToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSEnumerator* enumerator = [self.attachmentCells keyEnumerator];
        NSString* existingAttachmentID = nil;
        while (existingAttachmentID = [enumerator nextObject]) {
            UICollectionViewCell* cachedCell = [self.attachmentCells objectForKey:existingAttachmentID];
            if ([cachedCell isEqual:cell]) {
                [keysToRemove addObject:existingAttachmentID];
            }
        }

        for (NSString* key in keysToRemove) {
            [self.attachmentCells removeObjectForKey:key];
        }

        [self.attachmentCells setObject:cell forKey:attachment.ID];
        [(UICollectionViewCell<QMChatAttachmentCell> *)cell setAttachmentID:attachment.ID];

        __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
        // Getting image from chat attachment service.
        [[ServicesManager instance].chatService.chatAttachmentService getImageForAttachmentMessage:message completion:^(NSError *error, UIImage *image) {
            //
            __typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;

            if ([(UICollectionViewCell<QMChatAttachmentCell> *)cell attachmentID] != attachment.ID) return;

            [strongSelf.attachmentCells removeObjectForKey:attachment.ID];

            if (error != nil) {
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
            } else {
                if (image != nil) {
                    [(UICollectionViewCell<QMChatAttachmentCell> *)cell setAttachmentImage:image];
                    [cell updateConstraints];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
}
```

But in New Quickblox api image is not opening `onClick`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck at this. I am answering too late but It may help someone else facing same issue.

There are two different cells for `IncomingChatAttachmentMessage` and `OutgoingChatAttachmentMessage`. To handle tap on these, `QMChatCell` provides delegate. You just need to set delegate to your class and override the below method:

```
- (void)chatCellDidTapContainer:(QMChatCell *)cell;
```

This method handles the tap on cells. You need to check if the tapped cell is a attachment message and then pass the image accordingly.

You can refer this question on Github on [QMChatViewController issues](https://github.com/QuickBlox/QMChatViewController-ios/issues/120).